# I deleted my database in android studio and now I can't retrieve it. What should I do?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

So I wanted to look at my database so I went to the device file explorer in Android Studio, went to my package and to the databases folder and I downloaded my database to see in sqliteonline.com. But I noticed that I had a data wrong so I wanted to start over, so I deleted it.

I thought that if I re run my android it would generate the database again in the folder. But it didn't. I'm not sure how I can see my database now.

What should I do?

Comment: The database gets created on first call to e.g. `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`.

Comment: And now apps works fine like when had DB  ? or app crashes ? I think you are right and app should recreate DB. U can try to go to android settings -> apps -> select your app -> click on `clean storage` maybe it can help.